# How to find the operator $T*$

Tags: linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $V= M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an inner product space defined by $\langle A, B\rangle = Tr(AB^*)$

Let $T\in Hom(V,V)$ be a linear operator defined by $T(A)=P^{-1}AP$ for $P \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Find $T^*$

I tried to approach it in two differnt ways :

First is to use the fact that for every matrix $A$:  $A^* = \overline{A^T}$

I found that the inner product $\langle A, B\rangle = Tr(AB^*)$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i\overline u_i$ where as $v_i$ is a row of A and $\overline u_i$ is a row of $B^*$

I don't know how to proccceed from there.

The second way I tried was to use the formula $\langle T(A), B\rangle = \langle A, T^*(B)\rangle$ but couldn't find a breakthrough there as well.

**questions:**

1 - Which way do you recommend ?

2- How do I procceed in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\langle A,B \rangle =Tr(AB^*)$ we get
\begin{align}
\langle T(A),B \rangle & = Tr(T(A)\, B^*)\\
&=Tr(P^{-1}AP \, B^*) \\
&=Tr(A\,\,\color{red}{PB^* P^{-1}}) \ \ \textrm{ (since $Tr(MN)=tr(NM)$ for any $N,M$ in $V$) }
\end{align}

But we know that $$ \langle T(A), \, B\rangle =\langle A, \,T^*(B)\rangle=Tr(A \, \color{red}{(T^*(B))^*})$$
Thus, the adjoint operator $T^*$ must satisfy
$$
(T^*(B))^* = P B^* P^{-1} 
\implies 
\boxed{T^*(B) = (P^{-1})^* B P^*}. 
$$

Comment: I was right there! can't believe I missed it. Thanks :)